# remove all occurences of a specific attribute from a XML

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML file with content like

> ```
> <document>
>   <section>
>     <section SectionName="abstract">
>      <paragraph>
>     <word Endpoint="1" SciomeSRIE_Sentence.ExposureSentence="1">gutkha</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">and</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">what</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">role</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">if</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">any</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">nicotine</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">contributes</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">to</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">the</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">effects</word>
>     <word ExposureSentence="1">split_identifier .</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">Adult</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" Sex="1" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">male</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" Species="1" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">mice</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">were</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">treated</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">daily</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" ExposureSentence="2">for</word>
> ```

I want to remove all occurences of "ExposureSentence" attribute. Output would be

> ```
>   <word Endpoint="1" SciomeSRIE_Sentence.ExposureSentence="1">gutkha</word>
>     <word >split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word >and</word>
>     <word >what</word>
>     <word >role</word>
>     <word >split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word >if</word>
>     <word >any</word>
>     <word >split_identifier ,</word>
>     <word >nicotine</word>
>     <word >contributes</word>
>     <word >to</word>
>     <word >the</word>
>     <word >effects</word>
>     <word >split_identifier .</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >Adult</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" Sex="1" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >male</word>
>     <word EB_NLP_Tagger.Participant="3" Species="1" AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >mice</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >were</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >treated</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >daily</word>
>     <word AnimalGroupSentence="1" DoseGroupSentence="1" >for</word>
> ```

I tried following, but not sure how to proceed futher.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        NodeList sectionNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("section");
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionNodeList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node sectionNode = sectionNodeList.item(i);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath makes this straightforward:

```
public static void main(String... args)
        throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

    // Find word elements with ExposureSentence attribute
    XPathExpression query = xpath.compile("//word[@ExposureSentence]");
    NodeList words = (NodeList) query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.getLength(); i++) {
        // Remove the attribute
        ((Element) words.item(i)).removeAttribute("ExposureSentence");
    }

    // Handle ComponentName
    query = xpath.compile("//ComponentName");
    NodeList componentNames = (NodeList) query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < componentNames.getLength(); i++) {
        String content = componentNames.item(i).getTextContent();
        componentNames.item(i).setTextContent(
            Arrays.stream(content.split(","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .filter(s -> !s.equals("ExposureSentence"))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }

    // Omitted: Save the XML
}
```

Comment: that worked. One minor question. How to remove a text from a specific node.Example:, I have <ComponentName> Animal, ExposureSentence, entity</ComponentName> in the end of the file and wants to remove ExposureSentence from there too.

Comment: I am getting error "The method setTextContent(String) in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments (Stream<String>)"

Comment: I think there are missing brackets. I made it work locally. Though unable to edite your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1631306 ah sorry. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest solution will be to replace all occurrences of `ExposureSentence="1"` using a simple regex. Read all the xml contents as String and replace all the specific word occurrences where you do not need XML parsing and replacing.

In case of XML parsing, you have parse, manipulate the logic and you have to rebuild XML infoset.

Comment: What an exceptionally poor idea. Even ignoring char-set related issues if you intend to read the XML document as a string, it will immediately fail if a document e.g. contains <word>ExposureSentence="1"</word>.